# Wcf service works in .NET Core 3.1 console app, but fails to work in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, winhttp, .net-core-3.1

Running into a peculiar issue at work. Trying to connect to an https, custom client certificate based connected service. I'm using BasicHttpsBinding and ChannelFactory classes to create a client for the service.

Able to connect to the service and get the response back on a 3.1 console app but when i put the same code in a 3.1 Web API controller it fails when i try to call the same operation using the client with the error **"There was no endpoint listening at .... This may be caused due to incorrect soap action". Inner exception says "winhttp exception. The server name or address could not be resolved"**.

I tried running fiddler to see what was different and for the console app i see a tunnel being established to the external service URL but for the call from within Web API I see nothing on Fiddler which means it's failing somewhere within the Web API pipeline itself.

Searches on Google point to checking proxy settings as this is on a corporate network but **netsh winhttp show proxy**  shows **direct (no proxy server)** so i don't think it's a corporate proxy related issue.

**What exactly is different in the network stack between a 3.1 console app and Web API that a WCF service call might fail in Web API but work in console app?**

Code in question

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://service url"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ExternalServiceInterface>(binding, endpoint);
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatepath, password);

_client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

var sbmtGtDtResp = _client.ExternalServiceOperation(data);
```

Have removed sensitive info like the service url and replaced the name of the interface generated on adding Connected Service to project by ExternalServiceInterface. 
**Getting an exception at _client.ExternalServiceOperation()** in .NET Core 3.1 Web API but works in .NET Core 3.1 Console App

Exception dump

```
{System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at "https://service url" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (80072EE7, 12007): The server name or address could not be resolved
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.StartRequest(WinHttpRequestState state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(HttpRequestException requestException, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsyncInternal(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at generatedProxy_1.submitGetDataRequest(submitGetDataRequestRequest )
   at WebAPIPOC.Controllers.ServiceController.Process() in "Code filepath.cs":line 50
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()}
```

Comment: This how this works. You need to post the relevant code so we can replicate it and try to solve the problem.  Otherwise how can we determine what the solutions is?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Got it, will update in some time

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Updated with code bit that raises exception when running from a .NET Core 3.1 Web API

Comment: Looks like a WCF client? .... Anyways the key to the error is this: "The server name or address could not be resolved"  .... That means it cannot find the server so most certainly  it is trying to connect to the wrong IP or DNS name... that error is not coming from the server but from the DNS not being able to resolve the domain.  Double check that it it is trying to reach the correct domain and that the service is actually listening on that address

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro yeah i would look into that, but i am able to connect to the same service when I write this same piece of code in a console app, both the web api and console app being on my work machine. That points to a difference in network stack handling between a web api and console app, and wanted to know more about that so that I can fix that. If it were an IP or DNS issue, the console app running on the same machine connecting to the same external service, should have failed too right? Even the target framework for both web api and console app is 3.1 as well

Comment: Just to make sure it is not a proxy issue put this line of code in your entry point somewhere early in the execution:   WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro That didn't work, but I was just reading a github issue thread on a slightly similar issue someone was facing, and updating System.ServiceModel.* Nuget packages resolved the issue for me. I'm kind of disgusted by my stupidity to not check that first. Will create an answer if someone else stumbles upon this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, as it usually is, was really stupid on my part. But incase anyone else makes the same mistakes as me I'll list it out.

Updating the `System.ServiceModel.*` Nuget Packages to their latest versions(from 4.4.0 -> 4.7.0) resolved this issue for me, don't know why older versions were being automatically installed when adding the WCF/Connected Service.

Had read up that newer versions of .NET Core no longer use WinHttp and instead use SocketsHttpHandler, and that should have alerted me to an old library being used as I was seeing a WinHttpException

And as to why it was working in a console app for me. I had 4.4.0 versions of the libraries there as well, but apparently to fix some reference error, I had manually installed `System.Private.ServiceModel` which is a dependency of `System.ServiceModel` and doesn't usually require manual installation. And I installed the 4.7.0 version of `System.Private.ServiceModel`. This somehow made the WCF service call work in the console app, even with the version mismatch between `System.Private.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel` packages

Github issue thread that led me to check the library version, with more details on why exactly old versions of library cause errors -  https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3311

Comment: @Pani I'm glad this was of help!

Comment: Thank you for this. I had some issue, different error message but working console and failing net core 3.1 web api. I checked the references and after updating all of them it works.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue. I was running a WCF client behind an IIS proxy. I was getting the error: 
WinHttpHandler is only supported on .NET Framework and .NET Core
on System.ServiceModel.* 4.4.0 .Upgrading to 4.8.0 fixed my issue.

Comment: After the update I need to refresh/update de reference to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I wasted 6 hours trying to fix this issue. In my case, I was trying to consume a soap in console and getting "There was no endpoint listening at https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/services/SweaWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint that could accept the message soap" error. After visiting this answer, I updated all ServiceModel packages: `System.ServiceModel.Duplex` `System.ServiceModel.Http` `System.ServiceModel.NetTcp` and `System.ServiceModel.Security` to v4.7.0 and now its getting responses properly. Although the current question and accepted answer is for netcore3.1, my console app is in dotnetcore 2.1 so I am assuming it has to do with overall wsdl importing process, since the packages get installed through scaffolding process.