# Not able to see use all WSDL content on .NET Core Web API

Tags: wcf, .net-core, webapi

I'm not able to see all of the methods of the Web Services that I want to use on my .NET CORE Web API project on Visual Studio 2019.
Unlike on a Console Application project that I used to work with and add the .WSDL through the "**Add Connected Services**" method.

2 projects. Same WSDL. Different results.

Here's an example of the method that I need to use and it's there (AuthenticateUser) :
[image]

Here is how it looks on reference file on the Console Application project :
[image]

Here is a screenshot from the .NET CORE Web API project which the **AuthenticateUser()** method cannot be found on the reference file :
[image]

Same service, different result.

I've already seen some posts here such as :
[Wcf service works in .NET Core 3.1 console app, but fails to work in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908213/wcf-service-works-in-net-core-3-1-console-app-but-fails-to-work-in-asp-net-cor)

Doesn't seems to be working for me.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are the URLs the same for both?

Comment: AuthenticateUser() should generate an asynchronous method in the reference that does not affect usage.

Comment: @LanHuang yes the URLS are the same. I want to use the regular one. not the Async.
It somehow doesn't appear on the Web API project

Comment: But it can be seen from the code you generated that you use System.Threading.Tasks , do you use it on the server side?

Comment: @LanHuang both codes were generated automatically with the Connected Service > Add Service Reference. The problem is that on the Web API it shows less methods than the Console Application. I have a built code that I want to use on the Web API but it just doesn't recognize some of the methods.